# Starting MySQL Cluster

Tags: mysql, database, cluster-computing

Im new to clustering and Im doing a project on cluster database. I want to make use of MySQL Cluster. Im using it for a small scale database and this is my plan:

5 node:
1 management node,
2 SQL node,
2 API node.

My questions are:

1) Is my plan for the node process alright?

2) What should I do when I got the error "Failed to allocate node id..."?

3) Is it a requirement to use multi-threaded data node?

4) Where do I place my web server page for the user to access the database?

Please reply. Thank you so much.

Comment: This question is better suited for dba.stackexchange.com

Comment: And it is a good idea to split this into several questions as there in fact are several questions.

Answer (score 1):

This answer might be a little late but can be helpful for someone else getting started:

> 1) Is my plan for the node process alright?

Your plan for the node process is ok for a small cluster. I would recommend adding an additional management node and 2 more Data Nodes if the number of replicas you have configured is 2. Reason being since you currently have only 2 data nodes, your cluster will not be functionally should once of those nodes "die" . This is because of the two-phase commit that takes place. In the case of a faiure only 1 data node will be able to persist the data , the other one would be unreachable and therefore the transaction would be marked as incomplete.

> 2) What should I do when I got the error "Failed to allocate node
>   id..."?

This error is usually thrown if you have assigned the same id to other nodes in your configuration file. Each node should have a unique Id.

> 3) Is it a requirement to use multi-threaded data node?

It is not a requirement but recommended. Using mulch-threaded data node allows you to leverage modern computer architecture with multiply cpus to allow for your data processing queries to be processed much faster. As a result updates and queries will be done much faster

> 4) Where do I place my web server page for the user to access the
>   database?

Hmm.Not sure why you want to achieve here. This would be a separate  question, if you are using PHP or usually any other language. You will have to have a web server configured. Place them in the root of the http directory to get started